# Deploy Metadata with Apex Testing Using REST : No package.xml found

Tags: deployment, metadata, apexrest

I have explored below two options to deploy metadata into my salesforce account.

**Option 1:**
Bundle zip file is available here: [bundle zip](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KVIh_KLhrGd_JZ5kJocU9RYbBAGEtKoQ)
I am able to upload the bundle zip using workbench [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDeploy.php) with API version 54.0
**This is working fine.**

**Option 2:** This option is not working for me. Trying to upload the same using Rest API listed in [Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm).

[My zip file structure](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KVIh_KLhrGd_JZ5kJocU9RYbBAGEtKoQ)

[image]

I have generated base 64 encoded string using this [online tool](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file)
Base 64 encoded string is here: [base64 string](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KVIh_KLhrGd_JZ5kJocU9RYbBAGEtKoQ).

Now my postman invocation is like this:
url: `https://krishna52-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v54.0/metadata/deployRequest`
headers:

```
Authorization:Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------BOUNDARY
```

Raw body:

```
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "deployOptions": {
    "allowMissingFiles": true,
    "autoUpdatePackage": false,
    "checkOnly": false,
    "ignoreWarnings": true,
    "performRetrieve": false,
    "purgeOnDelete": false,
    "rollbackOnError": true,
    "singlePackage": true,
    "testLevel": "NoTestRun"
  }
}
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";filename="simple2.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

<Base 64 encoded string>

----------------------------BOUNDARY--
```

Response:

> 201 Created, Deployment Id also returned.

When I check the status of this deployment in salesforce application or from postman, I am always getting

> component failure "No package.xml found".

```
"id": "0Af5g00000nAIO0",
.........
.........
"componentFailures": [
{
    "componentType": "",
    "fileName": "package.xml",
    "fullName": "package.xml",
    "id": null,
    "problem": "No package.xml found"
    .......
} ]
```

Do I have to enable any permissions for my account to perform this Rest operation ? If that is the case, I should get different error saying unauthorized.

But I am able hit API and track the deployment statuses from deployment pages of salesforce application.

In option 2, what else is missing? I have gone through existing Q&A links, but even after followed those steps, I am getting same problem.

With this new Q&A thread, I really wish to have sequence of steps to get my option 2 works.

Request you to verify the steps I am performing and help me in this regard.
I really appreciate yours' expertise here.